# control child container scrollbar in parent container

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

**Scenario:**

I have a parent div containing the table headers and a child div containing the table data.

**Aim:**

I want to be able to scroll horizontally which scrolls all content left to right and, if the table data overflows vertically, I want to be able to scroll vertically with the headers in view.

**Problem:**

If the table data overflows vertically and the width exceeds the parent container, I can't see the vertical scrollbars unless I scroll along, hence the title.

I set up an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/uRHkU/2/ - is what I'm trying to achieve possible?

```
<div class="parentDiv">
    <p>very very very long header</p>
    <div class="childDiv">
        <p>content that stretches the full width</p>
        <p>content that stretches the full width</p>
        <p>content that stretches the full width</p>
        <p>content that stretches the full width</p>
        <p>content that stretches the full width</p>
        <p>content that stretches the full width</p>
        <p>content that stretches the full width</p>
        <p>content that stretches the full width</p>
        <p>content that stretches the full width</p>
        <p>content that stretches the full width</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `overflow: auto` on "parentDiv" and remove all the overflow-xy-Stuff.

Comment: Didn't work, if I scroll vertically, the headers are out of sight. http://jsfiddle.net/uRHkU/4/

Comment: Still missing the point - "If the table data overflows vertically and the width exceeds the parent container, I can't see the vertical scrollbars unless I scroll along"

Answer (score 0):

You have at least 2 ways to obtain your horizontal scrolling
Keep in mind that is your paragraph element who is overflowing!!

**Alternative 1**
Use

```
.parentDiv
{
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow:auto;

}
.parentDiv p {
    display:inline;
}
```

And you will get a scroll  bar for all the set

**Alternative 2**

```
.parentDiv
{
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;

}
.parentDiv p {

    overflow:auto;
}
```

And here you will get a scrolling bar for the paragraph

*Edited comment: You can omit the inline rule for the paragraph. As in this fiddle. I hope its what you were looking for .*
Fiddle here [Child scrollbar Alternative 1](http://jsfiddle.net/Fico/fAnE8/)

Comment: Alternative 1: I don't want all the p elements inline, deliberately on different rows. Alternative 2: This doesn't work, I need both div scrolling horizontally together.

Comment: Yup, but if I scroll far enough right, I will not see the inner scroll bar or imagine the inner content has lots of content per row that the width exceeds the parent container width. I deliberately added width to the inner div.